Expo-router Tabs not working in a specific navigation folder unless I focus on inside pages and interact with buttons
I'm using expo-router to set up a Tabs layout and encountered an issue; the Tabs navigation doesn't work as expected in a specific folder structure; I am using tabs navigation for my audits folder and a more global navigation using a drawer. Here's what I'm observing:

Expected Behavior (Other Folders): For most routes, the navigation works seamlessly. Clicking on a tab immediately updates the view without requiring additional interactions, not that the only other navigation is a Drawer.
Problematic Behavior (Some Folders): For specific routes (like the Audits [id] dynamic folder or the Audits index), navigation doesn't seem to function correctly unless I explicitly focus on the inner pages by interacting with buttons or manually navigating deeper into the folder structure. Even then, the Tabs navigation feels inconsistent.

Some unique characteristics of the problematic folder(s):

These routes may require additional configuration for navigation behavior, but I'm unsure what changes are needed.
The tabs is in a specific folder layout, folder that is called audits, maybe it is related to the two navigation methods that clash, the drawer and the tabs.

Here's my audits _layout code:
import { Tabs } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

import { HapticTab } from '@/components/HapticTab';
import { IconSymbol } from '@/components/ui/IconSymbol';
import TabBarBackground from '@/components/ui/TabBarBackground';
import { Colors } from '@/constants/Colors';
import { useColorScheme } from '@/hooks/useColorScheme';

export default function AuditsLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint,
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarButton: HapticTab,
        tabBarBackground: TabBarBackground,
        tabBarStyle: Platform.select({
          ios: { position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
          default: { backgroundColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].background },
        }),
      }}>
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <IconSymbol size={28} name="house.fill" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="new"
        options={{
          title: 'New',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => <IconSymbol size={28} name="square.fill" color={color} />,
        }}
      />
       <Tabs.Screen
        name="[id]"
        options={{
          title: 'Show',
          tabBarShowLabel: true,
          href: null, 
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}

Here's my Base _layout code:
    import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Stack, Tabs, useRouter, useSegments } from "expo-router";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "react-native-reanimated";
import "../global.css";
import { i18n, initializeLocale } from "../services/localization";
import { Provider, useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { AppDispatch, RootState } from "@/store/redux";

import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Drawer } from "expo-router/drawer";
import { DrawerToggleButton } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { store, persistor } from "@/store/redux";
import ConnectionStatusIndicator from "@/components/My components/ConnectionStatusIndicator";
import { monitorConnection } from "@/store/redux/connectionSlice";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import NavigationDrawer from "@/components/My components/NavigationDrawer";
import { themes } from "@/store/redux/themeSlice";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

function AppContent() {
  const { theme, settings } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.theme);
  const dispatch = useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
  const segments = useSegments(); // Get the current route segments

  const hideDrawerToggleRoutes = ["login", "password-reset", "+not-found"];

  const isHiddenRoute = segments.some((segment) =>
    hideDrawerToggleRoutes.includes(segment)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(monitorConnection());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={theme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>

    <SafeAreaView className={`flex-1 ${settings.SafeAreaView}`}>

      <StatusBar style={theme === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"} />

      <GestureHandlerRootView className="flex-1">
        {!isHiddenRoute && (
          <View
            className={`h-20 flex-row items-center px-4  ${settings.DrawerHeader}`}
          >
            <DrawerToggleButton />
            <View className="ml-2">
              <ConnectionStatusIndicator />
            </View>
          </View>
        )}

        <NavigationDrawer />
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </SafeAreaView>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
      initializeLocale();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <AppContent />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}


Could you edit the question to elaborate on what doesn't work correctly means? Specify the behaviour that you see with most folders and why that's as expected. Explain how the behaviour is different for some folders, and maybe any special characteristics of those folders.

Hey @SmellyCat,
i've updated the question.

After sitting on this for so long, the solution for me was to Update all my dependencies, now i dont really know what was it that solved it for me but its probably expo related.
